# how to run an application with user privileges from root console

Tags: linux, console, privileges

I run a bash script from Linux root console.
So this script runs an application with root privileges.

But I need an application to be called as user.

Can this scenario work as I expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sudo -u username` you can run a program with `username` privileges. Like this:

```
sudo -u youruser yourscript.sh
```

If you can't use `sudo`, you can try with the followind command, as @Torrius suggested:

```
su - youruser -c "yourscript.sh"
```

If you can't even use the latter solution, you can write a small c program that runs an executable with the privileges of parametrized `user and group id`.

Look at this concept code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./this [uid] [gid]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    setuid(atol(argv[1]));
    setgid(atol(argv[2]));

    execl("/usr/bin/whoami", "whoami", 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

To test it:

```
myshell:~ root$ ./a.out 501 501
davide

myshell:~ root$ ./a.out -2 -2
nobody

myshell:~ root$ ./a.out 1 1
daemon
```

Comment: Your answer is fully completed in a common, but I try to do this in a project where `sudo` is restricted. Have you any new ideas? If no I will complete this.

Comment: Answer updated with a further option

Comment: This way may be useful also. `su - username -c "bash_script"`

Comment: Thank you @Torrius, i added your suggestion in the answer